# How to create custom methods to swipe my view up and down, Espresso - ViewActions

Tags: android, android-espresso, swiperefreshlayout

I want to create custom methods to swipe my view up and down, for example 25% down/up, or any other cases.
I tried to override methods like this:

```
public static ViewAction swipeDown(){
    return new GeneralSwipeAction(Swipe.FAST, GeneralLocation.CENTER, 
            GeneralLocation.TOP_CENTER, Press.FINGER);
}
```

But it's only from top to center and i need shorter ones. I wanted to use new CoordinatesProvider() :

```
public static ViewAction swipeDown(){
    return new GeneralSwipeAction(Swipe.FAST, new CoordinatesProvider() {
        @Override
        public float[] calculateCoordinates(View view) {
            return new float[0];
        }
    },
            GeneralLocation.TOP_CENTER, Press.FINGER);
}
```

...and it might be an answer, but i don't really know how to calculate coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

`Robotium` has already `drag()` function which is pretty similar to `swipe[Direction]` functions in Espresso, but it already uses defined coordinates.

> `* @param fromX X coordinate of the initial touch, in screen coordinates
>        * @param toX X coordinate of the drag destination, in screen coordinates
>        * @param fromY Y coordinate of the initial touch, in screen coordinates
>        * @param toY Y coordinate of the drag destination, in screen coordinates
>        * @param stepCount how many move steps to include in the drag. Less steps results in a faster drag`

Check https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium/blob/b69dcf740baabec48c91999e523377faef79682e/robotium-solo/src/main/java/com/robotium/solo/Solo.java

You can use both frameworks along or try to rewrite `Robotium`'s `drag` function in your own way.

This might be handful: https://github.com/piotrek1543/robotium-showcase